# Animation background in all activities

Tags: android

I need to run an animation in background for all my activities.

I have 2 issues:

1.- This background animation has to be fixed, not change with the activities transition. I think the best solution is a background activity playing this animation while the other (transparent background) activities are over it

2.- I have to move the animation position in background activity. How could i communicate to this background activity that the position has to be changed from the foreground activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it using fragments. Keep the animation part running on one fragment and use other fragments to display transparent background activities.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is fragment is API level 11 and i'm developing for 2.3 (API 10). I'l need other solution but thakns anyway.

Comment: You can implement fragment in lower API levels as well. For this you need to do follow these steps:- Add android-support-v4.jar to you project.  Find this jar at SDK-PATH/extras/android/compatibility/v4/.   Copy this into your libs folder in the root of your project and add it to your project build path.   Use FragmentActivity instead of Activity.   To get FragmentManager use getSupportFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager.